# Are there any transaction-related artifacts left in the database?

Tags: security

Bitcoin writes to some log files (bitcoin/*.log and bitcoin/database/log.nnnnnn )

Are these (and everything else other than wallet.dat) clear of any information that would allow a forensic investigation to determine which addresses a bitcoin installation had sent or received?

Reworded question from:
 - http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=63488.msg743339#msg743339

Comment: Related, but narrower, question: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/does-the-berkeleydb-based-wallet-dat-implementation-leak-private-key-data

Answer (score 1):

Some (one?) of the *.log files are connected to your wallet.dat address database, knowing your bitcoin addresses implies knowing your transactions.

One (debug.log) is free format debugging text and may contain all kinds of identifying info.